# Unable to switch to Google sign in window - Katalon

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-signin, katalon-studio

I am trying to switch to Google sign in window but the test is failing.

[image]

I am using the command :

```
WebUI.switchToWindowTitle("Sign in - Google Accounts")
```

But the test fails with

```
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Cannot find window with title: 'Sign in - Google Accounts'
```

Also I tried with

```
WebUI.switchToWindowIndex(1)
```

But the test fails with

```
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Cannot find window with index: '1'
```

Does someone knows how to switch to the google sign in window?

I was able to successfully switch to PayPal sign in popup window using the same switchToWindowTitle command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed on [Katalon forum](https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-switch-to-google-sign-in-window/60377/24) and has been answered [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en), as well:

> To help protect your account, Google doesn’t let you sign in from some browsers. Google might stop sign-ins from browsers that:

> - Don’t support JavaScript or have JavaScript turned off
> - Have unsecure or unsupported extensions added
> - Are being controlled through software automation rather than a human
> - Are embedded in a different application